# Can I ask a question regarding showing times?

Tags: discussion

I come from StackOverflow and asking for offsite resources is a close reason. I've only lurked on movies.SE and was wanting to ask a question regarding showing times for a particular service.

For example;

- How soon after a cinema showing will movie *x* be listed on UK Netflix

But more specifically, my question relates to [BBC iPlayer](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer) and [Orphan Black](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2234222/?ref_=nv_sr_1), and I was unsure if the following question would be considered offtopic here at movies.SE;

- How soon after the showing on BBC America will Orphan Black S3E1 be listed on BBC3 iPlayer?

<sup>I apologise if this is off-topic here. I've searched the internet to find the timings but to no avail. I was hoping some Movies & TV enthusiasts would be able to shed some light for me.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to apologize, this is the right place to clarify such things!

**No** - these kind of questions are off topic and will be closed as either "too broad" or "questions about current events".

The reason why is that "how soon" type questions vary from movie to movie and a definitive answer is not something that we'd ever be able to provide. What works for one particular movie or TV show may be completely different for another, and really the only people who can answer these kinds of question with any authority are under a non-disclosure agreement to specifically not do that. There is no way for us to find out this information before the rest of the internet and once the rest of the internet knows, any "how soon" question would be basically asking for us to Google that information for you.

They're also a source of speculation and discussion, which is not really what Movies & TV Stack Exchange is about. (or, the overall goal of Stack Exchange, for that matter)

These are the kind of questions that expire - they're only valid for a small window of time and then their value is no longer relevant as the content is freely available.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the info @Flyk!